# Visual basic 2010 vbulletin Loader

Tags: vb.net, vbulletin

I am trying to create a vbulletin Loader for my site.

The main question is how to create a loader for vbulletin

The Loader works so it has permissions from vbulletin; if a user is a V.I.P., then he/she has access to inject a V.I.P .dll.  A regular user can't inject that .dll, only limited to some not all and they cannot download the .dll. I am currently working on the login and its not working, nor that secure.

Module1.vb code;

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

Public Function Login(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String)
    Password = MD5(Password)
    Dim valid As Boolean = False
    Dim data As String = "vb_login_username=" & Username & "&vb_login_password=&s=&do=login&vb_login_md5password=" & Password & "&vb_login_md5password_utf=" & Password

    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.mywebsite.com/login.php?do=login")
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.UserAgent = "-- vBulletin Vaidation  --"



        request.ContentLength = data.Length

        Dim rStream As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream)

        rStream.Write(data)
        rStream.Flush()
        rStream.Close()

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
        Dim resReader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

        Dim str As String = resReader.ReadToEnd


        If str.Contains("Successful Login!") Then
            valid = True
        Else
            valid = False
        End If


        response.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Failed to connect to www.mywebsite.com", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try

    Return valid

End Function

Public Function MD5(ByVal number As String) As String

    Dim ASCIIenc As New ASCIIEncoding
    Dim strReturn As String = String.Empty

    Dim ByteSourceText() As Byte = ASCIIenc.GetBytes(number)
    Dim Md5Hash As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim ByteHash() As Byte = Md5Hash.ComputeHash(ByteSourceText)

    For Each b As Byte In ByteHash
        strReturn &= b.ToString("x2")
    Next

    Return strReturn

End Function

End Module
```

Form1 code;

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox("Copyright Notice: Copyright website 2013 - 2014 All Rights Reserved. - Click 'OK' to lunch Loader.")
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        My.Settings.mystring.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Login(ComboBox1.Text, TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Successfully Logged In!")
        Me.Show()
        Me.Close()

    Else
        MsgBox("Unknown Username and Password. Try Again.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to create a loader for vbulletin.

Comment: You may want to edit your question so that your question is more obvious.